# Use HTTP response data within spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I am very new for Spring Boot and web services. I implement Spring Boot app to save products to database. It works fine. Now I want to use product price for some calculations.

As an example I have unit price for all products. When user select product and number of units he wants to buy from front end, I'll pass the product ID and number of units to a API method which will calculate total amount he wants to pay.

I have below method to get product details according to the product ID.

```
@GetMapping("/products/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Product> getProductById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long productId)
    throws ResourceNotFoundException {
    Product product = productRepository.findById(productId)
      .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Product not found for this id :: " + productId));
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(product);
}
```

It gives me below response.

> {
> "id": 8,
> "name": "Penguin-ears",
> "cartonPrice": 175,
> "unitPrice": 9.0,
> "unitForCarton": 20
> }

So I want to use this unitPrice within another method. How can I do this?

Comment: I think you've to look at the design first.Your end goal is to calculate the price so as you already mentioned that you got the response so utilize that value in another api method to calculate the item price.

Comment: @harry yes that is I want to know. How to use one api response within another api call

Answer (score 0):

Usually the `Controller` calls the `Service` layer with the logic that, if needed, calls the `Repository` level.

So in your case, you can have a `Service` class with a public method of `getProductById`.
This method returns an object. Not JSON.

The `Controller` will call this `service` class and will translate the object to JSON.

Your new endpoint will call another method in the `Service` class (maybe `buyMe`?).

And `buyMe` is a method that sits in the same `Service` as `getProductById`. So it's easy to call one method from the other.

Answer (score 0):

The way you should follow is this:

1. `Controller`
2. `Service`
3. `Repository`

Firstly in the `Controller` we take care of the endpoints and we delegate the work to our `Service`. For your use case I would use a `DTO` (Data Transfer Object). Basically you pack some different properties int one java POJO, like this:

```java
public class BuyEnquiryDto
{
    private int productId; // You could also pack these into an array if you have several Products
    private int quantity;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Then in the controller:

```java
@Controller
public class Controller
{
    private ProductService productService;
    
    public Controller(ProductService productService)
    {
        this.productService = productService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/products/buyProduct")
    public ResponseEntity<Product> buyProduct(@RequestBody BuyEnquiryDto buyEnquiryDto )
    {
        return this.productService.buyProduct(buyEnquiryDto);
    }
}
```

Then we have the service which takes care of the Business logic:

```java
public class ProductService
{
    private ProductRepo productRepo;

    public ResponseEntity<Product> buyProduct(BuyEnquiryDto buyEnquiryDto)
    {
        int productId = buyEnquiryDto.getProductId();
        
        productRepo.findById(productId).orElseThrow(...smth);
        
        /// Your logic continues here, you may also want to return something else, maybe the total price...
    }
}
```